# How to take snapshot of a viewcontroller without loading in screen in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

In my iPAD application, I have two viewcontrollers, first viewcontroller has a button, I want to get the **snapshot of second viewcontroler** when I click on that button, without loading the second viewcontroller in iPAD screen.
If I load the viewcontroler and then take snapshot then it is working but my requirement is to do the same without loading the viewcontroler in screen.
Please give idea or link or code snippet.

Comment: How do you want to take a snapshot of a VC that's not loaded in the view controller stack, yet?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Show the code and explain what it did wrong.

Comment: i think if i make instance of VC and then some how there is a way to take snapshot..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:-
Make instance of VC that you want to take screen shot, and then pass the object in this method.

```
+ (UIImage *)renderImageFromView:(UIView *)view withRect:(CGRect)frame {
// Create a new context the size of the frame
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, YES, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Render the view
[view.layer renderInContext:context];
//[view drawRect:frame];

// Get the image from the context
UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

// Cleanup the context you created
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return renderedImage;
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't work if you are using SpriteKit in your view.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is based on Dheeraj Kumar's answer, but this will work if your view contains SpriteKit contents as well. It requires iOS7, though.

The code in Swift, for the ViewController with the SpriteKit view,

```
private func takeScreenshot() -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Not part of the question, but you can then share your screenshot very easily,

```
    if let image = screenshot as? AnyObject {
        let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just instantiate your second view controller, and take a screenshot, like:

```
- (void)foo
{
   UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondVC"];
   UIImage *screenShot = [self imageFromView:vc.view];
   // Do something with screenShot
}

- (UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *) view
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    }
    [view.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```